# Appium крашит приложение телефона

Tags: java, android, appium

Решил изучить Appium но наткнулся на ошибку. В приложении калькулятора пытаюсь сложить два числа. Приложение в телефоне падает и закрывается. Пробовал на эмуляторе и разных устройствах.

Прилагаю логи IDEA (на сервере ошибка 500)

```
 rg.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new
 remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original
 error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
 command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.huawei.calculator'
 application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the
 'com.huawei.calculator' application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name
 '.com.huawei.calculator' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot
 be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity Build
 info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
 '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1',
 os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
 java.version: '18.0.1.1' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
 remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred
 while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the
 'com.huawei.calculator' application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the
 'com.huawei.calculator' application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name
 '.com.huawei.calculator' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot
 be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
     at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server
 GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
     at asyncHandler (C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server
 GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
 '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1',
 os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
 java.version: '18.0.1.1' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
 io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
 at
 io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
 at
 io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
 at
 io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)  
 at
 io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
 at
 io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:363)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
 at
 io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init(AppiumDriver.java:89)  
 at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init(AppiumDriver.java:99)  
 at
 io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init(AndroidDriver.java:97)
 at tests.initialize(tests.java:26)   at
 tests.checkCalculate(tests.java:35)   at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)   at
 org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
 at
 org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
 at
 org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
 at
 org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
 com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
 at
 com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
 at
 com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
 at
 com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
 at
 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
 at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)   at
 io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:193)
 ... 83 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
 unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 Original error: Cannot start the 'com.huawei.calculator' application.
 Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the
 'com.huawei.calculator' application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name
 '.com.huawei.calculator' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot
 be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity Build
 info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
 '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.56.1',
 os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
 java.version: '18.0.1.1' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
 remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred
 while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the
 'com.huawei.calculator' application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Cannot start the
 'com.huawei.calculator' application. Visit
 https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md
 for troubleshooting. Original error: Activity name
 '.com.huawei.calculator' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot
 be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
     at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server
 GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
     at asyncHandler (C:\Users\%USER_NAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server
 GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:380:37)
 at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
 at
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
 at
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
 at
 java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at
 java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
 at
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
 at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
 ... 85 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос закрывается, имя экрана было выставлено не то. Поставил на нужное и всё заработало.